# R script on android

Tags: java, android, r, google-app-engine

I am writing android app with java and google app engine. I need to run R-script in my code to analyze some data. 
So now I am looking for a way to run this sctipt on google app engine or any other solution, but still didn't find solution.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about trying smth and share a piece of code?